# CGGradient and path clipping: strange border around the clip

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to reproduce an example in the book **iOS Programming: Big Nerd Ranch Guide 4th edition**.

Note that I rewrite in Swift all the Obj-C code in the book.

As a challenge, the book requires to draw this triangle-shaped gradient, using Core Graphics:

[image]

But when I run my code, I notice a litte grey border surrounding the triangle:

[image]

I can't understand why.... this is my code:

```
    ....
    // draw circles
    UIColor.grayColor().setStroke()
    path.stroke()

    let logoImg = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
    let realSize:CGSize = logoImg.size.halve() // get a /2 CGSize in order to calculate non-retina size

    let gradientLocations:[CGFloat] = [0, 1]
    let gradientColors:[CGFloat] = [0, 1, 0, 1,
                                    1, 1, 0, 1]
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradientColors, gradientLocations, 2)

    let gradientClipPath = UIBezierPath()
    gradientClipPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: center.x - realSize.width/2, y: center.y + realSize.height/2 + 30))
    gradientClipPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: center.x + realSize.width/2, y: center.y + realSize.height/2 + 30))
    gradientClipPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: center.x, y: center.y - realSize.height/2 - 30))
    gradientClipPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: center.x - realSize.width/2, y: center.y + realSize.height/2 + 30))
    gradientClipPath.fill()

    // draw gradient
    CGContextSaveGState(currContext)
    gradientClipPath.addClip()
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currContext, gradient, CGPoint(x: 0, y: center.y - realSize.height/2 - 30), CGPoint(x: 0, y: center.y + realSize.height/2 + 30), 0)
    CGContextRestoreGState(currContext)

    // draw logo with drop shadow
    ....
```

Setting stroke to clear ***or to other colors*** has no effect. Border is still there and it is still grey.

Comment: Is `gradientClipPath.fill()` meant to be in the code? I think that's a mistake. If that's not it I can't really help sorry, I always use `CAShapeLayer` these days and am out of practice with Core Graphics. Note: you really should avoid using core graphics in real world projects. Usually `CAShapeLayer` is better for drawing bezier paths.

Comment: I think the `fill()` should be there because it strokes the area where the gradient will be painted... no? Note that this is a challenge in the book so I wrote part of the code on my own. Thank you for the tip about CG.

Comment: Try taking the fill out, I think that's the part that is going wrong. Does it help if you don't fill it?

Comment: At home, I'll try and let you know, thank you.

Comment: Thanks... that worked... I come from Flash, there you use filled clipping masks. Please rewrite you comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to fill the gradient path prior to drawing the gradient. Remove this line:

```
gradientClipPath.fill()
```